# force a field to revalidate asynchronously in knockout validation

Tags: validation, knockout.js

I'm extending an existing app that uses knockout.js - but is very much not setup to support invalidating - so I can't use the knockout async validation - (I tried - race conditions happened).   So I'm rolling my own.  This *sort of works*.

```js
ko.validation.rules.my_validator = {
    validator( value ) {
       var known_result = already_validated[ value ];
       if (known_result == null)
       {        
           call_server_function_on( value ).done( function( result )
           {
                already_validated[value] = result;
                // somehow force a revalidate of THIS observable here
           })
           this.message = "validating...";
           return false;
       }
       else
       {
           this.message = known_result.message;
           return self.is_valid;
       }
   }
}
```

I can't find any way of forcing the revalidate.
If I pass in the observable as a parameter, I can then call notifySubscribers, and it all works - but that makes for a really horrible ui of my validator - eg

```js
someField.extend( {my_validator: {the_observable: someField }})

...
the_observerable.notifyObservers( the_observable());
```

Is there any way I can do it from inside the validator?

Comment: You could try to use `the_observable.valueHasMutated()` to access the observable in your validator you need to assign your viewmodel to a variable that you can access

Comment: Can you elaborate on the race conditions you were seeing?